# ASP.NET assign button onclick at runtime

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I am using ajax modal popup dialog to make users confirm their action. Since I have several scenarios where the user needs to confirm the action, I would like to re-use the same popup dialog, only changing which event is fired when the user click btnYes (confirming the action).
In code behind (VB) I assign the message for the popup:

```
    lblMessageConfirm.Text = strMessage
```

Then, before opening the dialog,  I would like to assign the event that btnYes will fire if the user clicks. I tried the methods  below and none seems to work:

```
    AddHandler btnYes.Click, AddressOf Test '(this event does not do anything)
```

And also

```
    btnYes.Attributes.Add("onclick", "Test") '(this returns an error “Test is undefined”)
```

Test1 is the sub I want to assign to “Onclick” and it is in the code behind in the page where the popup is set up:

```
    Protected Sub Test(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
     MsgBox("Test ")
     End Sub
```

I open the dialog:

```
     ModalPopupExtender2.Show()
```

Here is the html for the popup – it does show up, so the only problem is trying to assign onclick event. When I add the “onclick” in the HTML, the Test sub runs

```
<cc1:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="cbe" runat="server" 
DisplayModalPopupID="ModalPopupExtender2" TargetControlID="lnkDummy">
</cc1:ConfirmButtonExtender>
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server" 
 PopupControlID="pnlPopup2" 
 TargetControlID="lnkDummy" 
 CancelControlID="btnNo" >
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup2" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" 
 Style="display: none">
                <div class="ModalHeader" runat="server">
                    Please Confirm ...
                </div>
                <div class="ModalBody" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMessageConfirm" runat="server">
</asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="ModalFooter">
                 <asp:Button ID="btnYes " runat="server" 
CSSClass="ModalButton" Text="OK" />
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
```

With the following code Test runs:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnYes " runat="server" CSSClass="ModalButton" Text="OK" 
onclick="Test"/>
```

I have this working with 2 Yes buttons and making the correct one visible based on the scenario, but adding more scenarios where the user needs to confirm will mean adding more buttons...

Comment: `MsgBox` should not work in ASP.NET...

Comment: `MsgBox("Test ")` is a WinForms' message box, not webforms... you need to use JS `alert` method (and probably `RegisterClientScriptBlock` in code-behind) instead.

Comment: the VB Message box is just a test to make sure sub Test() runs